# Redis Sorted Set Member Size and Performance

Tags: sorting, redis, node-redis

Redis Sorted Sets primarily sort based on a Score; however, in cases where multiple members share the same Score lexicographical (Alpha) sorting is used. The [Redis zadd](http://redis.io/commands/zadd) documentation indicates that the function complexity is:

> "O(log(N)) where N is the number of elements in the sorted set"

I have to assume this remains true regardless of the member size/length; however, I have a case where there are only 4 scores resulting in members being sorted lexicographically after Score.

I want to prepend a time bases key to each member to have the secondary sort be time based and also add some uniqueness to the members. Something like:

```
"time-based-key:member-string"
```

My member-string can be larger JavaScript object literals like so:

```
JSON.stringify( {/* object literal */} )
```

Will the sorted set zadd and other functionality's performance remain constant?

If not, by what magnitude will performance be affected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The complexity comes from the number of elements that need to be tested (compared against the new element) to find the correct insertion point (presumably using a binary search  algorithm).

It says nothing about how long it will take to perform each test, because that's considered a constant factor (in the sense that it doesn't vary when you add more items).

The amount of data which needs to be compared before determining that a new element should go before or after an existing one will affect the total clock time, but it will do so for each comparison equally.

So your overall clock time for an insert will be quickest when comparing scores only, and  progressively slower the deeper into a pair of strings it has to look to determine their lexical order. This won't be any particular magnitude, though, just the concrete number of microseconds to be multiplied by the log(n) complexity factor.

Comment: So to make sure I understand your answer correctly: the amount of time it takes to perform the comparison is equal for each comparison regardless of the member string size?  Member string size doesn't affect time complexity when performing inserts. Time increases only as the number of members in the sorted set increases even if sorting logic falls back to lexicographical member sorting.

Comment: If the time taken to make each comparison doubles (as a simple example), the time taken to perform an insert, with the same number of items in the list, will also double. But it won't change the number of comparisons that have to be made. You can't say that it will affect the complexity, because you're just doubling an unknown number. An O(n) search could take an hour for each item, or a nanosecond, all the complexity predicts is how many hours, or nanoseconds, for a value of n.

Comment: So the comparison time is a constant factor for each test (number of members in sorted set) but is also increased by the complexity of the comparison. Thus an increase in member string size increases the time per comparison and resulting total time. It would be nice for the documentation to include details on this secondary sort so that they may be considered when implementing the store...

Comment: @user3331119 I don't think there's a "secondary sort" as such. Sort algorithms are based on comparing pairs of values; for a given pair, a callback function must say which value should sort first. All that needs to happen in this case is for that callback function to look like "diff := score a - score b; if diff == 0 then diff := lexicaldiff(value a, value b)" Again, the documentation has made no claims about that comparison callback, just as it lists no details of how the memory for the list is managed, or any number of other details which will affect its performance.

Comment: thanks for all the great responses. What I meant by secondary sort is the fallback logic to use lexicaldiff if score is identical which you have nicely coded out into a callback function. In my example, "time-based-key:member-string", would the lexicaldiff consider only the "time-base-key" in the case the key had no duplicates? I'm wondering if the lexicaldiff will NOT need to analyze the entire string if there is an obvious sorting decision earlier in the string???  Hence, prepending the "time-based-key" to the member string will be the main factor on comparison time.

Comment: I have found that by definition lexicographical order is based on the first difference found in string. That would mean the main factor in my example for comparison time would be the "time-based-key". Thanks again!